# ffmpeg: Ошибка при сохранении или конвертации видео в формат .mp4

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4

На моем хостинге - *ffmpeg* установлен как модуль *php*.
У меня возникают ошибки при конвертации видео в формат mp4

Ошибка:

> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect
>   parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Пример команды ffmpeg:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /home/afk/public_html/webroot/files/video.flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc /home/afk/public_html/webroot/files/video_text.mp4 2<&1
```

эту команду запускаю через функцию php exec() в скрипте:

```
exec( $command, $res);
```

А вот результат, который мне выдает (массив $res):

> Array ( 
>   [0] => ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers 
>   [1] => built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) 
>   [2] => configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect 
>   [3] => libavutil 54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100 
>   [4] => libavcodec 56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100 [5] => libavformat 56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101 
>   [6] => libavdevice 56. 4.100 / 56. 4.100 
>   [7] => libavfilter 5. 11.102 / 5. 11.102 
>   [8] => libavresample 2. 1. 0 / 2. 1. 0 
>   [9] => libswscale 3. 1.101 / 3. 1.101 
>   [10] => libswresample 1. 1.100 / 1. 1.100 
>   [11] => libpostproc 53. 3.100 / 53. 3.100 
>   [12] => Input #0, flv, from '/home/afk/public_html/webroot/files/video.flv': 
>   [13] => Metadata: 
>   [14] => title : Title of the video 
>   [15] => encoder : Lavf56.25.101 
>   [16] => Duration: 00:00:24.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1364 kb/s
>   [17] => Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 500x500, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc 
>   [18] => [libx264 @ 0x1ec6720] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX 
>   [19] => Output #0, mp4, to '/home/afk/public_html/webroot/files/video_text.mp4': 
>   [20] => Metadata: 
>   [21] => title : Title of the video 
>   [22] => encoder : Lavf56.25.101 
>   [23] => Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 25 fps 
>   [24] => Metadata: 
>   [25] => encoder : Lavc56.26.100 libx264 
>   [26] => Stream mapping: 
>   [27] => Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv1 (flv) -> h264 (libx264)) 
>   [28] => Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height 
>   )

Та же самая ошибка выходит при конвертации любого видео в этот формат.
Уже использовал примеры из документации ffmpeg, но ошибка остается.
Помогите разобраться и решить эту проблему.

При этом нормально работает конвертация из формата *flv* в *ogg*
Или создание видео из изображений в форматы *flv* и *ogg*

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте явным образом не указывать -acodec